# Nest.js AuthGuard JWT returns 401 unauthorized

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs

Using Postman to test my endpoints, I am able to successfully "login" and receive a JWT token. Now, I am trying to hit an endpoint that supposedly has an AuthGuard to ensure that now that I am logged in, I can now access it.

However, it constantly returns 401 Unauthorized even when presented the JWT token in Postman.

Here is my code:
auth.controller.ts

```js
@Controller('auth')
export class AuthController {
  constructor(private readonly authService: AuthService) {}

  @AuthStrategy(AuthStrategies.LOCAL)
  @Post('admin/login')
  async login(@Request() req) {
    console.log(req.user);
    const token = this.authService.issueToken('admin', req.user);
    return { type: 'bearer', token };
  }

  @UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'))
  @Get('admin/me')
  getProfile(@Request() req) {
    return req.user;
  }
}
```

jwt.strategy.ts

```js
@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, 'jwt') {
  constructor(
    private readonly authService: AuthService,
    private readonly configService: ConfigService,
  ) {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      ignoreExpiration: false,
      secretOrKey: configService.get('jwt.secret'),
    } as StrategyOptions);
  }

  async validate(payload: JwtPayload): Promise<any> {
    const { sub, model } = payload;
    if (!sub || typeof sub !== 'number') {
      throw new UnauthorizedException('请先登录');
    }
    const user = await this.authService.findByPk(model, sub);
    if (!user) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException('该用户不存在');
    }
    return user;
  }
}
```

app.jwt.module.ts

```js
export class AppJwtModule {
  private static factory(configService: ConfigService): JwtModuleOptions {
    const jwtConfig = configService.get('jwt');

    return {
      secret: jwtConfig.secret,
      signOptions: {
        expiresIn: jwtConfig.expiresIn,
      },
    };
  }

  static registerAsync() {
    return JwtModule.registerAsync({
      useFactory: AppJwtModule.factory,
      inject: [ConfigService],
    });
  }
}
```

auth.service.ts

```js
  issueToken(model: ManagerModel, user: object): string {
    const payload: JwtPayload = { sub: user['id'], model };
    return this.jwtService.sign(payload);
  }
```

auth.module.ts

```js
@Module({
  imports: [AdminModule, PassportModule, AppJwtModule.registerAsync()],
  controllers: [AuthController],
  providers: [AuthService, JwtStrategy, LocalStrategy],
  exports: [AuthService, JwtModule],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

[postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oz4fQ.png)

I am at a lost as to what could be the issue here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.